# Read a column file in julia

Tags: io, julia

I would not like to pickaxe a lot in the language just to read a file with numerical data arranged by columns. Is there an easy way to do this now in julia 1.1? Surprisingly this simple task is not on the manual. In python one would do something like this:

```
def read2col(filename, length):
    data = []
    for line in open(filename,'r'):
        for word in line.split():
            data.append(word)

data = np.reshape(data,(length,2))
data = np.asarray(data, dtype=np.float64)
return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(untested)

```
function read2col(filename, len)
    asfloat64(s) = try x = parse(Float64, s); return x catch; return missing; end
    data = []
    for word in split(read(filename, String), r"\s+")
        push!(data, word)
    end
    data = reshape(data,(len, 2))
    data = asfloat64.(data)
    return data
end
```

or even

```
asfloat64(s) = try x = parse(Float64, s); return x catch; return missing; end
read2col(fname, len) = asfloat64.(reshape(split(read(fname, String), r"\s+"), (len, 2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't tried yet the last suggestion but the first one is almost there, one only needs to remove the last character `data[end] = ""`.

Comment: You can trim the file with trim(read(fname, String)) to get rid of your trailing blank lines. The DelimitedFiles solution handles trailing blank lines well but crashes if one of the entries is nonnumeric. You may also need to decide what to do if the nunber of entries is not even, since that would crash the functions too.

Answer (score 4):

There is already an inbuilt function in Julia that does exactly that:

```
using DelimitedFiles
reshape(readdlm("myfilename.txt"),:,2)
```

Let's give it a spin:

```
shell> more file.txt
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12

julia>  reshape(readdlm("file.txt"),:,2)
6×2 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.0   8.0
  4.0  11.0
  7.0   3.0
 10.0   6.0
  2.0   9.0
  5.0  12.0
```

or if you want a different ordering just transpose with `'`

```
julia>  reshape(readdlm("file.txt")',:,2)
6×2 reshape(::LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}, 6, 2) with eltype Float64:
 1.0   7.0
 2.0   8.0
 3.0   9.0
 4.0  10.0
 5.0  11.0
 6.0  12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The laziest way to do it is to use CSV.jl

```
using CSV
for row in CSV.File("file.txt",delim=' ',ignorerepeated=true)
  println("a=$(row.a), b=$(row.b), c=$(row.c)")
end
```

delim=',': a Char or String that indicates how columns are delimited in a file; if no argument is provided, parsing will try to detect the most consistent delimiter on the first 10 rows of the file